# How to set image to center crop in Floating Action Button

Tags: android, xml, android-widget, floating-action-button

I wanted to put user Profile Image inside the FAB but its size appearing on it is real small, how to center crop it..

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_blurrhgrh"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|start"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dev_pic_crop"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried adjustViewBounds or scaleType? You can set scaleType to centerCrop

Comment: tried but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer,

```
app:maxImageSize="64dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: FAB size constraints]

The FAB does not provide entire real estate to display the icon/image. Hence, the icon is given limited space, as shown in the image. Scaling won't help you to display the icon on the entire FAB space.Should that stop you from achieving what you want?
No, What you could do is Override original resources in dimensions.xml or you can create your custom FAB. Follow the link given below.
https://blog.stylingandroid.com/floating-action-button-part-1/